# How to concat observable values in the desired order instead of all the values of each one separately?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a for each loop in which I create three observable, each of them call an API, with a parameter returned by my loop.

I would like to successively get the first value of my first observable, next the first value of my second observable, and next the first value of my third observable. After that, the second value of my first observable, etc...

Here, with the concat function, I get all the value from the first observable, after all the value from the second observable, and finally all the value from the third observable.

Which function do I have to use to achieve it?

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.serviceData.currentService.subscribe(service =>
        this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles().pipe(
          switchMap(familles =>
            forkJoin( 
              familles.map(f => forkJoin(
                this.serviceAffecter.getAffecterServiceFamille(service, f.nom),
                this.serviceOpe.getOperationsServiceFamille(service, f.nom)
                ).pipe(
                map(([listAffecter, listeOperations]) => [f, listAffecter, listeOperations])
                )
              )
            )
          )
        ).subscribe((data: [Famille, Affecter, Operation][]) => {
          this.familles = data.map(d => d[0]);
          for (let d of data) {
            const f = d[0];
            this.listeAffecter = d[1];
            this.listeOperations = d[2];
            for (let a of this.listeAffecter) {
             //Here is where I concat my observables
              var accessoire$ = this.serviceAccessoire.getAccessoireByIdAffaire(a.affaire.id);
              var variante$ = this.serviceVar.getVarianteByIdAffaire(a.affaire.id);
              var affaire$ = this.serviceAffaire.getAffaireById(a.affaire.id);
              var combined$ = concat(accessoire$, variante$, affaire$)
              combined$.subscribe(data =>
                //And data is what is returned by combined$
                console.log(data),
                this.points.push({
                  "value": this.getTAT(a.dateEntree),
                  "name": a.affaire.accessoire.nom + " " + f.nom +
                    " " + a.affaire.variante.nom + " " + a.affaire.sn,
                  "operateur": "PERSONNE",
                  "affaire": a.id
                })
              );

            }
            for (let o of this.listeOperations){
              this.points.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                if(o.affecter.id === arrayItem.affaire){
                  arrayItem.operateur = o.operateur.id;
                }
              });
            }
            this.element = document.getElementById(f.nom) as HTMLElement;
            this.element.innerText = "";
            this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.points, {dateDimension: false, color: "teal", labelFormat: "%Y"});
            this.points.length = 0;
            this.operation.length = 0;
          }
        }),
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    this.serviceData.changeAffaire(4);
  }
```

Please can anybody help me ?

Comment: Is your question: "How do I read data from a `concat` response?

Comment: @Silvermind I would like to get accessoire$, variante$ and affaire$ values at each loop iteration

Comment: You mean you want them before the next loop starts? It's a bit vague what you want. Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem?